# Symfony doctrine supply an array for where clause

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to add an array for $qb->andWhere(). This is my code.

```
$fuel_type = array("petrol", "diesel", "gasoline");
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
$qb->andWhere('c.fuelType = :fuel_type')
            ->setParameter('fuel_type', $fuel_type);
return $qb->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

I need to check traverse through $fuel_type values and check them in where. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, service or something else just do something like this

```
$fuel_type = array("petrol", "diesel", "gasoline");

$result = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Name')->findBy(['fuel_type'=> $fuel_type]);
```

Or directly in Repository

```
$fuel_type = array("petrol", "diesel", "gasoline");

return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.fuelType IN (:val)')
        ->setParameter('val', $fuel_type )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro but is there a way to do this in repository level?

Comment: Sure, check the new response

Comment: Just a note to: `'App:Entity'`, it's deprecated in Symfony Doctrine bundle for years, use full class name instead: `App\Entity::class`